# Java Jersey - How can i write a file in my Tomcat Server

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

I got a problem in writing the file to the localhost of the tomcat server in my system.

How can i write file in the location mentioned Below ?? I am getting a response as the file uploaded in the location mentioned. But i don't know where it is stored in my system.. Is it the right way of doing ??

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/Attachments"
            + fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) { 
  try { 
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File( uploadedFileLocation)); 
    int read = 0; 
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024]; 
    out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation)); 
    while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) { 
      out.write(bytes, 0, read); 
    } 
    out.flush(); 
    out.close(); 
  } catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  } 
}
```

Actually I got this [writeToFile] code from http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

Comment: Can you show how you implemented `writeToFile()`, too?

Comment: private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
   String uploadedFileLocation) {

  try {
   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
     uploadedFileLocation));
   int read = 0;
   byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

   out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
   while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
   }
   out.flush();
   out.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
Actually I got this code from [link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the file to the same server as the web server, you uploadedFileLocation should be a directory such as `uploadedFileLocation = "/your_uploaded_file_direcoty/";` other than a HTTP URL.

If you want to write the file to a remote server via http, you can use some http framework.

Comment: The same has been working in case of writing in local file system say D:/UploadedFiles/filename.txt. But how can i do the same in the server

Comment: i think the problem here is the code `String uploadedFileLocation = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/Attachments" + fileDetail.getFileName();` that indicates you're writing file to a remote server. You can simply change to 'uploadedFileLocation = "/your_uploaded_file_direcoty/"' which should work fine. But be sure you have the sufficient permission to write to that directory.

Comment: If i Give simple a directory where the file will be written in the My computer.

Comment: i think that is what you intend. You give the uploadedFileLocation value as 127.0.0.1, which implies your're going to write the file on the same machine as the web server runs.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to write to a `File` called `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Attachments/something.else`. That is surely not going to work; according to [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29):

> If the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason then a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.

Since you just print out your Exception stacktrace, but don't handle the failure, you don't get an indication that writing the file failed. Check your server log, there'll be a stacktrace stating the file you're trying to access cannot be found.

Instead, generate a filename, for example `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + fileDetail.getFileName()`, and write to that file. The [JavaDoc for the `File` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) states:

> On UNIX systems the default value of this property is typically "/tmp" or "/var/tmp"; on Microsoft Windows systems it is typically "C:\WINNT\TEMP".